# Which takes faster for a computer to do: if (x == 0) or if (!x)

Tags: performance

Which is better coding practice, I'm sure that depends on what happens at the machine level.

Should I do

```
if (x == 0)
```

or

```
if (!x)
```

Comment: better coding practice is whichever one makes sense: are you testing for exactly 0, or are you testing for "not set".  performancewise they should be virutally identical.

Comment: Be careful of early optimization.

Comment: "I'd still like to know which is better coding practice and I'm sure that depends on what happens at the machine level." - WRONG. Micro-optimisation like that is a waste of time. There will be no practical difference, especially once a compiler has optimized it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard not only it's wrong for optimizations... but we don't know which language it is here. And for some reasons... the meaning of `!x` could vary to other languages considering that a `falsy` value isn't the same on all languages... and that it might all depends of the type of x.

Comment: Read this: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @KrisVandermotten It's still an interesting questions though.

Comment: @JeroenBollen no, it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best coding practice would depend on what you want to do. If you want to check if integer `x` is equal to 0, use `x==0`. If you want to check if boolean `x` is not true, use `!x`.

If you are looking for the most optimal code: **They both are equally fast.** Both statements do the same thing. They check for a flag being set. The compiler should know that you are trying to do equal things and thus produce the same or very similar output. **Especially after optimizations there shouldn't be any difference in performance.**

In `x86` processors these are usually done with a `cmp` operation, and a conditional jump. Respectively these compare two 'variables', or more correct *registers*, and does a conditional jump depending on the result (x being 0 for example).

Unless your compiler is 'derping' it should produce the same code regardless of the processor type (assuming the 2 conditions actually mean the same in your language).

---

I would also like to add, that **in weakly typed languages, especially when interpreted** (PHP for example) **there could be some overhead**. In that case it depends on if `x` is a boolean or intenger. These could just as well be optimized out though, and it's better to go with readability in any case. Any performance increase you will get is neglecible and readability is way more important. For example, `!x` might confuse people in thinking `x` is a boolean, while really it's an integer.

**Differences like these are interesting to know, but the performance gain is minimal, if it even exists.**

Comment: It is still incorrect because it could be... Javascript... Java C#... and so on and the meaning might be different in some cases.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix The compiler shouldn't make a difference between the two of them. That's just purposly making stuff complicated. This'd be the fastest way to do it, so why not do it?

Comment: because a "falsy" and "truthy" value isn't universal to every languages. And one way of doing things might give different results than what he expected... the question here is clearly not about performance. because the interpreter/compilator should optimize accordingly.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I updated my answer about a minute ago. I think that is what you mean.

Comment: you *could* have a language where some of that syntax is just wrong. This is a terrible question on account of it being about every/no language.

Comment: Both statements aren't equivalent. You could have an Object that overloads the `==` operator. but `!x` will be truthy if the object exists.

Comment: @thecoshman It's safe to assume the OP isn't completely retarted and the two statements have the same result.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix In that case the statements wouldn't be identical in result. That clearly isn't what the OP meant.

Comment: compilers understand both the same.. it dosnt matter anymore. Back in the day it did however. Compilers are very smart now. Almost anything you code, for loops, statements, classes,  will compile to the way that the computer knows most efficient. Just type away.

Comment: @NightSky yeah exactly. I'm still quite conserned about potention overhead you can get by automated casting done by loosley typed languages.

Comment: @JeroenBollen "retarted?", he _retorted_ :)

Comment: @JeroenBollen it's not safe to assume anything of the sort. OP is asking for blanket 'which is better'. There is clearly no one answer to that. And what's this rubbish about assembly options and dynamic languages. It's all noise. Cut to the point, it's a bad question leading to bad programming.

Comment: @thecoshman Feel free to suggest an edit, it's a community powered website after all. It's hard to cut to the point when there isn't much information to start from. Besides that, I think explaining why something is is equally as important as giving the answer.

Comment: I would, but apparently people want the tedious stuff. The most important thing is always writing more readable code. You, amongst others, have jumped into assuming this is a certain language that performs in a certain way. And whilst a language like C++ will almost certainly produce identical assembly, that is irrelevant. OP asked which to use, and **NO ONE** can give a definitive answer to that. It is entirely case by case.

Comment: @thecoshman I did make that mistake but edited my answer several times to make it more global.

Answer (score 2):

Simple question, simple answer: none. Modern compilers know that both forms mean exactly the same thing, they will produce the same code in either case.

Just checked the output of `gcc`. This little program:

```
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    if(argc == 0) return 1;
}
```

compiles to the following assemble code (no optimizations):

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L2
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L1
.L2:
.L1:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

as does this little program:

```
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    if(!argc) return 1;
}
```

Comment: So that is C or C++ sorted... are you going to test what the output is for every other language that allows this syntax? You still haven't covered anything which is better practice.

Comment: @thecoshman No, I won't test each and every compiler. And I will certainly not give recommendations to which should be used, because it really doesn't matter which one you use. This is purely a matter of style, not of facts. There are people who prefer `if(!foo)`, and there are people who prefer `if(foo == 0)`.

Comment: People may prefer one over the other, but if they chose one other other out of nothing but personal preference they are terrible people. You use whatever works for your code. `foo==0` is for numerical types, `!foo` is for boolean types. You should never fall back on the terrible assumption that your language treats `0` and `false` as the same. Write code that is readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a meaningful question so let's just answer the question instead of constantly mentioning "early" optimizations, language, or even assuming the x86/x64 ISA since it could be some other microprocessor.
It depends on the compiler and microprocessor/ISA. Some processors have a register reserved for the value 0 (eg, MIPS), such that it need not be mem,reg compare but likely reg,reg0 followed by conditional jump.
The programmer may specify the comparison that occurs much more often, in which case, the optimized code is the fall though code avoiding the jmp penalty and possible bubble in the pipeline.
This may be important for some of us because we write real-time kernels.

Comment: I guess assuming a processor type was a mistake on my end yeah.

Comment: @JeroenBollen perhaps now you are seeing why this is a bad question. It is so generic the only 'correct' answer is 'it depends'.

Comment: @thecoshman There are plenty of people who will search for this anyways. It's good to have an answer for them, even if it means they have to search for something more specific.

Comment: @Robert Charon - just to clarify, you're saying that in this case `x==0` would perform faster, because of the dedicated 0 register on a MIPS.  Correct?  And that it could potentially be optimized even *further* by determining which case is likeliest to occur, and ordering the assembly instructions so that's the fall-through case.  Correct?

Comment: @FoggyDay Even if `x==0` would be faster, the compiler **should** be aware of this and optimize the second condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both have the exact same performance as they are interpreted the same way by the compiler.

Comment: But which one is the best coding practice?

Comment: It boils down to personal preference. I'd prefer x == 0 as it looks more intuitive. You could also argue that !x is less code. Your choice.

Comment: Unless 'x' is a boolean type. There is no place for personal preference.

Answer (score -4):

You use `x == 0` when you want to test that your numerical data holder 'x' has a value exactly equal to '0'. You use `!x` when your data holder 'x' is a boolean data type and you want to do something when that value is currently 'false'.

Mixing the numerical value '0' with the boolean value 'false' is **terrible**.

Write code that can be read and is easy to work with.

You can answer two things in this question. Which is faster: depends on the language, for the most part though, they are the same. Which is best practice: I can't say, that is context sensitive; again most languages will allow both forms, but use whatever make sense for your code.

Comment: Watch it with the language and the snark.